# Python selenium how to confirm the javascript message to open whatsapp Web

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I'm making WhatsApp automation script to send a message. When I run the script it asks the javascript confirm to open WhatsApp web.

How I can do that.?

My code :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import os
import mysql.connector



driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/evilslab/Downloads/chromedriver 3')

driver.get('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0097155000XXXX)

# Click the link to activate the alert
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "https://api.whatsapp.com wants to open this application.").click()



# Store the alert in a variable for reuse
alert = driver.switch_to.alert

# Store the alert text in a variable
text = alert.text

# Press the Cancel button
alert.dismiss()
```

This not confirming that